# make the selected text bold in textarea

Tags: javascript

I have got two *TextAreas* and i want to use one toolbar. The toolbar should contain buttons for making the text in the textbox bold, italic, align to the left and right, add bullet points etc.. What I don't get is: how can I make the selected text in the textarea **bold**? I was using an iFrame before for writing text and used the `iframe.contentDocument.execCommand()` for that purpose. But I think we can not use the execCommand() for a TextArea. To make it simple, I am just trying to make something like a TextArea which is identical to the TextArea when we post questions on stackoverflow, with a toolbar above it! But I don't know how to do operations on the text!

Comment: why not just use something like [CKeditor](http://ckeditor.com/)?

Comment: sorry i cant...cauze the job is to make sumthing like CKeditor :)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use textarea, because textarea [can only contain character data, that is unstructured text](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/textarea.html). Thus, all the contents of textarea have the same style.

That's why CKEditor, TinyMCE etc. use iframes.

Comment: hmmm thanks alot...but if u change the className of a textrea to "Bold"...it does makes the text bold....isnt this considered styling!?!?!